# About Connected sum of two manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

> I want to prove (i) and (ii). Is my proof of (iii) and (iv) correct?

Let $M_1$ and $M_2$ be two manifolds of the same dimension.

(i) Prove that there exist open neighborhoods $V  \subseteq  M_1$ and $V^{\prime}\subseteq M_2$ such that $V$ and $V^{\prime}$ are diffeomorphic to $B_{0}(2) $

(ii) Define $K, K^{\prime}$ as the image of the closed disk of radius $\frac{1}{2}$ around $0$.
Let $C= B_{0}(2) \setminus \overline{B_{0}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$. Prove that
$$
\chi: C \rightarrow C
$$

$$
\chi(x)= \frac{x}{\|x\|^{2}}
$$
is a diffeomorphism changing the interior and exterior bords of $C$.

(iii)- Let $\psi, \psi^{\prime}$ be the diffeomorphisms in $(i) .$ Let $\rho=\psi \circ \chi \circ \psi^{\prime}$ and let $M_1 \# M_2$ be the quotient space by the equivalence relation obtained by identifying points if they are equal or if one is the image of the other point under $\rho$ or $\rho^{-1}$. prove that $M_1 \# M_2$ is Hausdorff and second countable.

(iv)- Define a smooth structure on $M_1 \# M_2$.

for (iii) and  (iv) we have :
(let $h_{i}: \mathbf{R}^{m} \rightarrow$ $M_{i}, i=1,2,$ be two imbeddings.)

It follows immediately from the Invariance of Domain that:

$(*) \quad$ The projections $M_{i}-h_{i}(0) \rightarrow M_{1} \# M_{2}, i=1,2,$ are open maps.

This implies that $M_{1} \# M_{2}$ is second countable. We have to show that it is a Hausdorff space. (This is not immediate: The identification of $h_{1}(x, t)$ with $h_{2}(x, t)$ yields in general a non-Hausdorff manifold!) In view of $(*)$ this reduces to showing that if $x \in M_{1}-h_{1}(0)$ and $y \in M_{2}-h_{2}(0)$ have distinct images in $M_{1} \# M_{2},$ then they have neighborhoods with disjoint images. The verification is a routine case-by-case checking.

Now, the fact that $g_{2} \alpha_{m} h_{1}^{-1}$ is a (orientation preserving) diffeomorphism together with $(*)$ implies that the smooth structures on $M_{1}-h_{1}(0)$ and $M_{2}-h_{2}(0)$ are compatible, hence yield a (oriented) smooth structure on $M_{1} \# M_{2}$. (This is the unique structure for which projections in $(*)$ are diffeomorphisms.)